# Mismatch run time error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a type mismatch run time error with the following code.
Could someone tell me what I need to do differently?

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("L1:L15")
    Do While Not IsEmpty(MyRange)
      If MyRange > 1 Then
         Range(MyRange.Offset(1, 0), MyRange.Offset(MyRange.Value - 1, _
            0)).EntireColumn.Insert
         Range(MyRange, MyRange.Offset(MyRange.Value - 1, 1)).EntireColumn.FillDown
      End If
      Set MyRange = MyRange.Offset(MyRange.Value, 0)
      Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: A Type Mismatch simply means that you are trying to compare values that are not the same type.  You have to make sure that all of your values in that range are actually (say) numbers.  You can't compare (say) a date to a number, without an error.

Comment: Good idea to update your question to explain what your code is intended to do.

Answer (score 3):

It's in this line.

```
If MyRange > 1 Then
```

You are trying to compare a `Range` object against a `Numeric` value of 1.

What is your intent with that line? If you want to know values in each cell of that `Range`, you'll have to write a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to loop through each cell in the range, assuming you are looking at the cell values:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim c as Cell
    Set MyRange = Range("L1:L15")
    For each c in MyRange.Cells
      If c.Value > 1 Then
         Range(c.Row, c.Column + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
         Range(c.Row, c.Column + 1).EntireColumn.FillDown
      End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

I'm not clear on what you're trying to do in the middle there, so it may need some tweaking.